# different commands for file copy linux

Tags: linux, scp

I'm doing my first steps in working with linux, and my googling for this question didn't work out. So, I might be asking the wrong question, but I'll even THAT would be a helpful response.

We're dealing with copying big volumed files between two linux servers. We came across s_copy, scp and some other commands to do it. Are there any specific parameters in choosing between the methods? Do they do different stuff that I'm unaware of?

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong site. Try superuser or askubuntu instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use `rsync` if it's available in your systems, due to its desirable capabilities when it comes to move large files around, such as data transfer compression, progress info and ability to recover the transfer in case of connection failure.

Something in the lines of this will do the job:

`$ rsync -avz --progress <your-local-files> username@remote-host:/remote/path`

Comment: Also, if you're transferring large files, I'd suggest adding --partial flag to the command suggested by asamarin in case something interrupts a transfer of a large file.

Comment: @MarcinKaminski Nice suggestion. As a side note, `-P` flag stands for both `--partial` and `--progress`, so the whole command can be summarized as `$ rsync -avzP <files> ...`

Comment: Thnx! I'll check on it tomorrow. Is there a reason we shouldn't have rsync in the system?

Comment: I think it's a pretty standard tool these days, but you never know... worst-case scenario it will be in the repos, since it's well known and widely used.